# Capturing Hand-written Signatures in GSP form

Tags: grails

Does anyone know how to capture a handwritten signature (from a tablet) in to a Grails form?

Comment: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/
I'm still fairly new to Java Development, I tought myself pretty much overnight. There is a lot I still don't know and that seemed to leave a lot of unanswered questions on how to integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Grails specific question, but check out the [jQuery UI Signature](http://keith-wood.name/signature.html) plugin of the [jQuery Signature Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks I did find that one before by searching. Wasn't really sure how to make it work, but I guess if that's it I'll figure it out.

Comment: ouch this question really hurt my ranking. I guess I shouldn't have asked.

Comment: Well, give one of them a try (I've used Signature Pad before) and if you have specific questions or problems start a new question for that issue.  It's generally much better here to try something and come with a specific question or problems.

Comment: I have revised my question and posted more details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283157/jquery-signature-panel-plugin