# JQuery Signature Panel Plugin

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

I've been trying to get a signature panel to work in grails. on the client side everything looks like it works, but I have been struggling on how to get the signature saved to the database record.

I've tried a couple different versions, the last one I ended up with came closest to describing how to use ImageMagic or the like using php, ruby, or python. However trying to do this in groovy left me lost because I'm still a little green on how to code. Also I'm not sure about using a 3rd party utility when this is going to be running on cloud foundry.

The plugin in called SignaturePanel, looks just like the other ones really...
[jes-sherborne/jquery-signature-panel-plugin](https://github.com/jes-sherborne/jquery-signature-panel-plugin)

Here is the code from my files.

First, create.gsp contains the Javascript code.

```
<title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <!--  jQuery signature element code begins here -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'excanvas.compiled.js')}"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery-1.4.4.min.js')}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery.signature-panel.js')}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery.signature-panel.css')}" type="text/css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function signatureOK(signatureData) {
            // Send the signature to the server and generate an image file.
            $.ajax({
                url:"processSignature",
                type:"POST",
                data:JSON.stringify(signatureData),
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    $("#latest-signature").attr("src", data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
            $("#sig-panel").signaturePanel("clear");
        }

        function signatureCancel() {
            alert("Cancelled.");
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sig-panel").signaturePanel({
                okCallback: signatureOK,
                cancelCallback: signatureCancel
            });
        });

    </script>
```

_form.gsp

```
<!-- Signature Panel Begins Here -->

    <label for="sig"><g:message code="salesOrder.sig.label" default="Customer Signature" /></label>
    <div class="fieldcontain" ${hasErrors(bean: salesOrderInstance, field: 'sig','error')} id="sig-panel" style="width: 500px; height: 150px; border: 0px none"></div>
    <canvas id="latest-signature" style="width: 500px; height: 150px; border: 0px none"></canvas>

<!-- End of Signature Panel -->
```

Controller

```
// Capture Customer Signature JSON Data, Processes to Image, and Stream to Database
    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SALES'])
    def processSignature() {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'salesOrder.label', default: 'Signature'), ])
        // groovy code here 
        // We need to read the JSON POST data
         InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
         log.info(body) // nothing happens here
    }
```

Here is one of the Ruby examples I'm trying to figure out how to do in groovy.*(or if there is a better way... on the client side one can just right click and save the image. not really sure why this is so difficult for me)

````
### Generating image files on the server using Ruby

The Ruby library uses ImageMagick to generate a `Magick::Image` object, which you can use to write image files or stream the data in a variety of formats (PNG, JPEG, etc.). By default, the function will generate an image with the same pixel measurements as were originally captured on the client. You can also specify the size of the generated image, and SignaturePanel will scale the signature appropriately to fit within these bounds.

To generate the image, you will write code like this:

```ruby
require 'signature-panel.rb'
...

post '/process-signature' do
    image = SignaturePanel::GenerateImage(request.body.read)
    filename = 'latest-signature.png'

    image.write(filename)

    # If you want to stream your PNG directly to a database instead of saving a file,
    # you can get a binary stream like this:
    # image.to_blob {self.format = "PNG"}

    content_type :text

    # Send the name of the newly-generated file to the client
    body filename
end
```
````

So my question once again is, how does one save the signature along with all the rest of the form data in to the database using groovy?

Also from my domain class I should mention

```
byte[] sig

sig nullable: true, maxSize: 1048567
```

Once we get this challenge solved, we can put this puppy to bed ; )

Comment: I have been making changes in the controller. I've learned for instance to get the JSON information, I changed up the code to use request.JSON

Comment: Question - do you need to have the data in an image format?  I've always just saved the JSON data into a text type field (like a CLOB in Oracle) and then used the library functions to show it on the page: `$("#signature-display").signaturePanel("drawClickstreamToCanvas", signatureData);` where `signatureData` is the JSON string.

Comment: I'm going to write this up as an answer in case it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always just saved the JSON data into a text type field (like a CLOB in Oracle) and then used the library functions to show it on the page:

```
$("#signature-display").signaturePanel("drawClickstreamToCanvas", signatureData);
```

where `signatureData` is the JSON string.

So you could change your domain class to include

```
String sig

sig nullable: true, maxSize: 1048567
```

This also allows you to do something I think is very cool, although whether it's useful or not depends on your app.  You can recreate and animate the actual signing of the signature:

```
$("#signature-replay").signaturePanel("animateClickstreamToCanvas", signatureData, callback);
```

The docs explain the optional `callback` function.  I've never used that though.

If you change part of your ajax call, removing the `contentType` line because you are sending straight text and setting the hidden field

```
type:"POST",
data:{"signature": JSON.stringify(signatureData)},
//contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //set the hidden field value
    $('#sig').val(JSON.stringify(signatureData));
    //show signature on same page as preview (optional)
    $("#latest-signature").signaturePanel("drawClickstreamToCanvas", signatureData);
},
....
```

And then add the hidden field in the form as

```
<g:hiddenField name="sig" />
```

So now when they enter the signature and hit "OK" the `processSignature` won't really do anything - just act as a placeholder.  The AJAX call will set the value of the hidden field on the page.  Then when they submit the entire form (with other data) the normal `save()` method will get `sig` as just another param and will automatically save it to a `sig` field in the domain class.

You could access the data as a normal string in the `processSignature` method as `params.signature` if you needed to:

```
def processSignature() {
    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'salesOrder.label', default: 'Signature'), ])
    def signature = params.signature
    log.info(signature)
    response.contentType = "application/json"
    render """{"ok":true}"""
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I can do fine with just the data.  So how would I get `signatureData` to `${domainClassInstance.sig}` when the form posts?

Comment: So what I'm trying to do now, is to Ajax the clickstream to the controller and then using `def JSONObject = request.JSON` and `def sig = JSONObject` not really feeling its gonna work, but worth a shot. : )

Comment: You've already made your data into a string, so if you changed part of your `ajax` call you should be able to access it directly in the controller.  I've added a bit to the answer for this.  Note - I haven't done exactly this, but close to it.

Comment: OK, final edit's to the answer I hope.  I think you are getting the 404 because you aren't rendering anything back, so it is trying to load `processSignature.gsp`  When I use your code with these changes I am able to get `params.signature` in the controller with a value like `{"dataVersion":1,"clickstream":[{"x":9,"y":66.39999389648...` and much more.

Comment: That took care of the 404 .Also I do see the params.signature in the console. I'm still not getting how to fill in the field tho. I tried <g:hiddenField name="sig" value="${signature}"/> but that's still null. Thanks for the time on this, It's really close now I can feel it. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "fill in the field?"  Do you mean display it on the same page after it is processed through `processSignature`?  If that is what you want change your ajax `success` function to call `$("#latest-signature").signaturePanel("drawClickstreamToCanvas", signatureData);`

Comment: Sorry, To clarify. We have to save the signature data with the rest of the customer information when we are creating the records.

Comment: For example I have another field for Order ID `<g:textField name="orderId" value="${salesOrderInstance?.orderId}"/>` I figured if I just did <g:hiddenField name="sig" value="${signature}"> it would work but so far that table column is still null. 
When we create a new sale the customer signs it, then we go in to view the sale and we can print it with their signature

Comment: OK, I see... so they will create the signature, enter some other info and then submit it all to be saved as a `SalesOrder`  So your `processSignature` really doesn't have to do anything besides act as a placeholder the way your doing the process.  The example docs for the library always process ONLY the signature using AJAX, not other data.  I'll make one more edit that will just place the data back into the form for the final `save` process to handle.

Comment: Your help and time is much appreciated. Thank you Kelly.

Comment: So I imagine the Reverse would be true. `$('signatureData').val(${salesOrderInstance.sig});`

Comment: That should work as well but make sure you use the `#` with the selector name to target that id: `$('#signatureData')`